# Understanding $resource and controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to understand the following pieces of code. If I understand correctly, below I have three resource objects that interact with REST server data sources (these objects are `CategorySrv`, `ArticleSrv` and `SearchSrv` respectively).

```
app.factory('CategoryService', function($resource) {
    return $resource('categories');
});

app.factory('ArticleService', function($resource) {
    return $resource('articles');
});

app.factory('SearchService', function($resource) {
    return $resource('articles/search');
});
```

Now, the question I'd like to ask if when is the controller's code executed? If I loaded the page, it would probably run only once. When will it run the next time? Controller's code doesn't run in a loop, but only when its methods are called from the view, or the portion of the page attached to this controller is loaded (AFAIK).

When this happens, the resource objects listed above are injected into the argument list and controller's function is called:

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $location, CategoryService, ArticleService, CartService) {


CategoryService.query(function(response) {
    $scope.categories = response;
});

ArticleService.query(function(response) {
    $scope.articles = response;
});

CartService.get(function(response) {
    $scope.cartInfo = response;
});
```

Do I understand this correctly? Also, what's the difference between `get` and `query` above?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The code won't be running in a loop, only when the controller is loaded.

$resource gives you the option to use `get` or `query`, the difference being that the `query` will immediately return an empty array or object depending on whether `isArray` is set to true.  This helps with rendering so that no errors are thrown when angular expects an array or object but instead gets undefined like you would for async actions.  When the response comes back with your data, the digest cycle will run since `$scope` has changed and it will subsequently re-render your view.

docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: So basically when the site is loaded, all those queries and get-s are executed, next the digest cycle will update the view (it will stop looping after it detects nothing is changing in the $scope) and that's it? No other actions after that?

Comment: Not in this context, no.  Just to be clear. The initial render will provide empty arrays.  Which may impact any ng-repeats you may have on your template and show a table or list not populated.  Once the response comes back then the array is populated and your view will re-render since the digest cycle detects changes to your scope.

Comment: In this case, you might get what seems to be 3 additional re-renders because your responses will come in at different moments.